# GPT ext4 partition recovery - invalid backup header

Tags: data-recovery, gpt, parted, gdisk

When I run from a LiveCD to try to recover a non-booting system, I run gdisk /dev/sda and get

```
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.
```

so I *think* I'm supposed to do `r` then `e` but when I do `e` it says:

```
e   load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
Recovery/transformation command (? for help): e
Warning! This will probably do weird things if you've converted an MBR to
GPT form and haven't yet saved the GPT! Proceed? (Y/N): Y
```

but now I guess I have to write to disk, but when I select `w` it threatens to overwrite my old partition table like:

```
Recovery/transformation command (? for help): w
Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!
```

so I say 'no' for now and then `v` to verify things, to which it responds:

```
Recovery/transformation command (? for help): v
No problems found. 3309 free sectors (1.6 MiB) available in 2
segments, the largest of which is 2014 (1007.0 KiB) in size.
```

So does that mean it fixed things and it would be okay to overwrite the existing partitions yet? I've already made a backup of the partition table using the `b` menu.

Comment: Is drive MBR or gpt? There even is hybrid, which is part MBR, part gpt which is not recommended. You have to do the w to write a new gpt table. If you have Windows 7 it probably was MBR and you do not want to convert to gpt.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/460233/cant-restore-my-gpt-data-with-gdisk OR: http://askubuntu.com/questions/460233/cant-restore-my-gpt-data-with-gdisk

Comment: Here's what I get when I run gdisk: `GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10 Partition table scan:   MBR: protective  BSD: not present APM: not present  GPT: present Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.` I'm running Debian Jessie. I used `w` and it wrote stuff, we'll see how it works, now running fsck.ext4, it's fixing lots of stuff and taking awhile.