# HDD is "Mounted On" multiple times

Tags: partitioning, mount, external-hdd

I’ve got an external HDD that I can’t seem to fix on my ubuntu machine. It auto mounts when I plug it in but then mounts at about 30 different points (I can access and view the drive properly from any of them).

[Mounting too many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p99SX.png)

I’ve tried formatting/removing partitions (I believe I did that correctly in the GUI) on both a linux machine and on a windows machine, Please see attached image, any suggestions on how to get this back to it’s original state?

`fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdhf: 14.57 TiB, 16000900660736 bytes, 31251759103 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes 
Disklabel type: gpt 
Disk identifier: D3FD84DE-EDFD-4D66-B5E0-0DC36C0604E9
 
Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdhf1  2048 31251757055 31251755008 14.6T Apple TV recovery


Disk /dev/sdgt: 14.57 TiB, 16000900660736 bytes, 31251759103 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes 
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D3FD84DE-EDFD-4D66-B5E0-0DC36C0604E9

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdgt1  2048 31251757055 31251755008 14.6T Apple TV recovery

Disk /dev/sdio: 14.57 TiB, 16000900660736 bytes, 31251759103 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D3FD84DE-EDFD-4D66-B5E0-0DC36C0604E9

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdio1  2048 31251757055 31251755008 14.6T Apple TV recovery

Disk /dev/sdiz: 14.57 TiB, 16000900660736 bytes, 31251759103 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt 
Disk identifier: D3FD84DE-EDFD-4D66-B5E0-0DC36C0604E9
 
Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdiz1  2048 31251757055 31251755008 14.6T Apple TV recovery

Disk /dev/sdiw: 14.57 TiB, 16000900660736 bytes, 31251759103 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D3FD84DE-EDFD-4D66-B5E0-0DC36C0604E9
```

---

`sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdj1` prints out this:

```
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sdj1: 31251755008 sectors, 14.6 TiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 5A3A0364-EA7D-4371-BE43-9F253100B5F8
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 31251754974
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 31251754941 sectors (14.6 TiB)
```

It's a 16TB disk. `fdisk` does show an error:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 16.38 TiB, 18000207937536 bytes, 35156656128 sectors
Disk model: easystore 264D
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3D9C05A7-3D2E-41AA-A00F-7BB3A979BE0C

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1     34       32767       32734   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdd2  32768 35156652031 35156619264 16.4T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Post this in question: `sudo parted -l` if only a few lines. And `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdX` where sdX is first drive or what external drive should be. May be sdf or sdb?

Comment: `sudo parted -l` prints out what looks like hundreds of entries.

Comment: Is this drive really 14.6TiB? If so it must be gpt, not MBR although some vendors do a proprietary sector size and create all sorts of issues. But it looks like  you have standard 512/4K sectors. Better to post output in question, so you can preserve formatting. IN comment it becomes difficult to read. Does fdisk or gparted give any errors like linked logical partitions? Or just show many partitions.

Comment: You have to post in question, not in comments. Then you can maintain or do formatting. You show a Microsoft reserved partition. Microsoft does that for all new drives as it is required before an install partition. But gparted or gdisk do a better job of creating gpt partitioned drives

Comment: Got the fdisk output posted in original question now. I ran a few gparted commands to format, remove/add partitions.  The disk is working and accessible but still showing around 30 or so /dev mount points (if that's the correct term).  No idea why.

Comment: Not familiar with Apple TV Recovery. Or is the type not correct?

Comment: Not sure why it is saying that now. I don't really know what I'm doing :(

Comment: Using gdisk, and listing all the 4 digit  codes it uses I found this: `af04 AppleTV recovery `. Never seen it, but not an Apple TV user. Is this drive for use with an Apple TV? Or formatted from a Mac?

Comment: No never been used with an Apple TV or plugged into a Mac. Only windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: If you have good backups, I would just run gdisk and a write to see if that fixes anything. Or try changing type to a common Linux type. https://askubuntu.com/questions/460233/cant-restore-my-gpt-data-with-gdisk My Linux partitions: `8300 Linux filesystem `  See example on changing to 8300: http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html